About Auth systems and workflow
like when i made any auth system , user registers and then logins , then a cookie is generated , now like to have the user state stored across the app , i use redux , and also on refreshing the state should be there i use redux persist, no problem till that , but like if the cookie is 1d (its expiry) , but the redux persist is stored permantly ,
also i have never seen in any production level app that the data is stored in persist , so how do they deal with of thing of persist and the expiry as cookie experies , so the user should see login but it see some data though the persist
So how is the system of auth work (tell me the best solution)
i used persist and the cookie gets expired so it should show me login , but it shows all the features as the frontend checks  user data from persist
here is a sample code of my frontend auth
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { Outlet, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";

const ProtectedRoutes = () => {
  const user = useSelector((state) => state.user.user);

  return user ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/" />;
};

export default ProtectedRoutes;


getting the user from the redux persist

Somewhere in your UI you should check the cookie/token/etc when the app mounts/renders, and update the appropriate state to indicate the cookie/token/etc is expired and force the user to your log-in flow. Your ProtectedRoutes already handles the redirection part if/when state.user.user is falsey, so you just need to handle invalidating the state.user.user state upon expiration.
Example Implementation:
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const cookie = useSelector(state => state.user.cookie);

useEffect(() => {
  if (isCookieExpired(cookie)) {
    dispatch(logout());
  }
}, [dispatch, cookie]);

Your "logout" action should clear any user and cookie state and when the app rerenders, the ProtectedRoutes component should bounce the user to your auth flow and Redux-Persist should persist that updated state.
It's up to you where in your app you wish to apply this logic, but the two places I'd recommend are either somewhere near the root app component or in your ProtectedRoutes component so the cookie is checked each time a protected route is accessed.
